# Android custom seekbar: Cannot get accurate position of the thumb in the OnDraw method

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-seekbar

I am trying to implement a custom SeekBar by extending AppCompatSeekBar. My intention is to Draw some elements over the thumb. I attempted to get the bounds of the thumb for this, but it is inaccurate on the first draw.

Here is what I do on my onDraw method:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    /*Rotates the seekbar, as I need it to be vertical*/
    canvas.rotate(-90);
    canvas.translate(-getHeight(), 0);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.accent));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    Rect thumbBounds = this.getThumb().getBounds();
    int offset = getThumbOffset();
    Log.d(TAG,"ThumbOffset:"+offset+ " RectX:" + thumbBounds.centerX());
    thumbBounds.offset(offset,0);

    canvas.drawRect(thumbBounds, paint);        
    canvas.drawText(Integer.toString(getProgress()),thumbBounds.centerY(),-thumbBounds.centerX(),textPaint);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

The first time it loads, looks like this (incorrect)
[image: off center bounds]

After I drag the thumb around, looks like this (correct):
[image: centered bounds]

Moreover, if I minimize the activity a couple of times, the bounds go crazy:
[image]

Therefore, I'm assuming that I'm getting the thumb bounds of a few frames into the animation. My question is, how do I compensate for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While I couldn't find a good way of getting the position directly from the thumb, I found [in this example](https://gist.github.com/yqritc/7b5c786930dfb9b47e7a) a nice way of  doing it indirectly. I needed only to adjust the measurements for the vertical bar. Put this code in the onDraw method:

```
    //Calculating the size of the text
    text = String.valueOf(getProgress() - maxValue);
    textPaint.getTextBounds(text,0,text.length(),textBounds);

    //The height of the displacement area of our bar (the height - the padding - the thumb size)
    int bottomPadding = getPaddingLeft() - getThumbOffset();
    int topPadding = getPaddingRight() - getThumbOffset();
    int height = getHeight() - bottomPadding - topPadding;

    float progressRatio = (float) getProgress() / getMax();
    float thumbOffset = getThumb().getIntrinsicWidth() * (.5f - progressRatio);

    // In our rotated canvas, positive x is higher, positive Y is more to the left
    float thumbX = progressRatio * height + bottomPadding + thumbOffset;
    float thumbY = getWidth() / 2f;
    //Since we rotate the canvas again when drawing the text, we need to translate the coords for the text
    float textX = thumbY - textBounds.width() / 2f;
    float textY = -(thumbX - textBounds.height() / 2f);
```